# How to change the text of customize button in a menu file with dataBinding?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, data-binding, android-mvvm

I have a toolbar with a menu that contains a custom button at the end and I want to change the text of this button according to the fragment's position in a view pager. But when I call the function that I used in the BindingAdapter which is **showButtonText** it doesn't being called

I already used this way with a text view and it's already worked but this customizes button within a given menu doesn't.

My code :

**BindingAdapter : **

```
@BindingAdapter("app:showButtonText")
fun showButtonText(buttonView: Button, resId: Int?) {
    buttonView.text = resId?.let(buttonView.context::getString)
        ?: buttonView.context.getString(R.string.next)
}
```

**custom button xml : **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.cupcake.jobsfinder.ui.create_job.CreateJobViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/background"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null"
            **app:showButtonText="@{viewModel.jobUiState.titleToolBar}"**
            android:textColor="@color/primary"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            tools:text="Next"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**menu file : **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_next"
        android:title="@string/next"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/custom_button"/>
</menu>
```

**view model :**

```
package com.cupcake.jobsfinder.ui.create_job

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.cupcake.jobsfinder.R
import com.cupcake.jobsfinder.domain.usecase.CreateJobUseCase
import com.cupcake.jobsfinder.ui.base.BaseViewModel
import com.cupcake.jobsfinder.ui.create_job.state.CreateJobUiState
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.asStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.update
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import javax.inject.Inject

@HiltViewModel
class CreateJobViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val createJob: CreateJobUseCase
) : BaseViewModel() {

    private val _jobUiState = MutableStateFlow(CreateJobUiState())
    val jobUiState = _jobUiState.asStateFlow()

    private val _event = MutableLiveData<CreateJobEvent>()
    val event: LiveData<CreateJobEvent> = _event


    fun handleEvent(event: CreateJobEvent) {
        when (event) {
            is CreateJobEvent.PageScrolled -> {
                onChangeIndexViewPager(event.index)
            }

        }
    }

    private fun onChangeIndexViewPager(index: Int) {
        _jobUiState.update {
            it.copy(
                titleToolBar = getTitleToolBar(index)
            )
        }
    }

  

    private fun getTitleToolBar(index: Int): Int {
        return if (index == 0) R.string.next else R.string.post
    }


}
```

createJobFragment :

I found a blank button with no text just an empty button

[This how should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUnF3.png)

[This how looks like actually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1x6nz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using:

```kotlin
_jobUiState.value = _jobUiState.value.copy(titleToolBar = getTitleToolBar(index))
```

**Update**

That seems nothing wrong with the code you share.
After trying your code in [my project](https://github.com/annasta13/Stackoverflow-Question-and-Answer), I found that somehing might be missing in your fragment.

In your fragment, you might have set the binding view model in the onViewCreated

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding.viewModel = viewModel
}
```

However, the make the layout observing the changes of your state flow, you need to set the binding lifecycle owner.

Add this code to the onViewCreated function

```
binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
```

The onViewCreated body should be as follows:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding.viewModel = viewModel
    binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
}
```

See lifeCycleOwner [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding#setlifecycleowner)

[This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59545195/mutablelivedata-not-updating-in-ui) will also be helpful for you.

Comment: Your answer contains code without explanation. It's better to include details about *how* your answer answers the question.